# Regex pattern help wanted

Tags: regex, rtf, tr1

The raw string is like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Shell Dlg 2;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sb100\sa100\f0\fs24\u30340?\u27494?\u35013?\u20998?\u23376?\u65292?23\u26085?\u22312?\u33778?\u24459?\u23486?\u21335?\u37096?\u30340?\u39532?\u20140?\par
\pard\f1\fs17\par
by: lena (11/26/09)\par
\par
}
```

What is the regex pattern that would replace all RTF tags following a slash with "" empty string except `\unumbers`?
The result should look like:

```
\u30340?\u27494?\u35013?\u20998?\u23376?\u65292?23\u26085?\u22312?\u33778?\u24459?\u23486?\u21335?\u37096?\u30340?\u39532?\u20140?
by: lena (11/26/09)
```

I tried `"\\\\\\w+|\\{.*?\\}|\\}"` which removes all that follows a backslash and all curly braces. The missing part is something like `\\!(\\\\u)`

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the tags you want to keep first and replace them.

```
# php
$str = preg_replace('/(\\\u[\d]+)|\\\+[\w\?]+|{.*?}/', '$1', $str);

# perl
$str =~ s/(\\\u[\d]+)|\\\+[\w\?]+|{.*?}/$1/g;
```

Comment: I meant replacing them with themselves. The first match `(\\\u[\d]+)` is the \u tags you want to keep, which is the replacement $1.

Comment: sorry confused a bit:
if i coding in c++ and not familiar with php or perl that much.